# Handling http-post requests in Drupal

Tags: files

Currently our application has a nice little feature where it can upload projects (.zip files) directly from our application to our current php based project display site.  We are currently exploring moving this project display server over to Drupal and I was wondering if Drupal could handle this kind of thing.  We currently send an http-post with all of the authentication information then our server sends back a response depending upon authentication success or failure, then the application sends another http-post which includes the .zip file.  Would this sort of work flow be possible with Drupal?  Are there any modules which might facilitate this?

Comment: The [Services Module](http://drupal.org/project/services) has everything you need :)

Comment: I've been looking into the services module and it does seem to be the thing I need.  Thanks!  Do you know of any resources that might help me figure out how to handle user authentication using this module.  I have not found many good resources for this module.